# How can I embed the OpenEars framework in my application?

Tags: iphone, xcode4, openears

How can I embed the OpenEars framework in my application?

When I download the sample project form this website http://www.politepix.com/openears/ it gives me 20 errors and (gcc- exit code 1 error)

If you have any tutorials for this project then please share it with me.

Comment: Your error is not descriptive enough to help. However, I tried to install the project on XCode 4 recently and had the following weird problem: To be able to codesign the project I had to right click the project file, show contents, edit the project.pbxproj file and delete the two lines that contain the string EB285458. For some reason it wouldn't let me codesign the project without doing that. And of course, you have to download the libraries and follow the instructions from that website.

Comment: thnx for the reply Jano.. I run the application through the iphone simulator .. when I debug it . it will give me  573 error(gcc exit code 1), if you have full code of this tutorial then plz give me the link .. thnx

Answer (score 1):

Without any description of what the errors are it's impossible to say what the issue is, but if you look at the first tutorial page for OpenEars here (this is what Jano is referring to):

http://www.politepix.com/openears/gettingstarted

And read onwards from the line "If (and only if) you get multiple build errors, you may have to take one more step of assigning the base SDK for the library and sample app" and follow the instructions and images there step by step, there is a good chance it will help with your problem. I agree with Jano that you should systematically go through the steps in the tutorial starting on the page I've linked and make sure you have downloaded the libraries and run the configuration script just as it says.

Jano, that is odd with the codesigning, I'll look into it.

Comment: All righty; if you ever want to show any of the error messages you get I'll be glad to help you then, but until then there's nothing more to do here. A couple of things about your question make it seem like you may not have followed any of the steps from the instructions, but if you have followed all of the instructions from beginning to end and it isn't working for you, it is probably more useful for you to ask for help at the OpenEars forums since it is much more geared towards lengthy troubleshooting processes with an installation: http://www.politepix.com/forums/openears